# "Loading Failed" when soft crediting to a Personal Campaign Page

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, pcp, personal-campaign-pages

I get a message indicating "Loading failed" when trying to credit a donation to a specific personal campaign page. I can successfully Soft Credit to the owner of the page and add "personal campaign page" as the type, but this isn't the same as crediting to a specific pcp. I was able to recreate this on the demo site - see attached.

Any ideas why in one pop up edit screen one auto fill box works but not the other? I got as far as Contribute > Form > PCP.js.tpl but was out of my depth trying to figure out what was wrong.[image]

Comment: Please show us the js error in your browser's console. Here's some more troubleshooting tips: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850

Answer (score 1):

You're right there was a javascript conflict affecting popup forms on the contribution search page. I've [submitted a fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6156) which will show up on the demo site tomorrow and in the next release (4.6.5).

For now, you can work around the problem by right-clicking the "edit" link from the search results screen and opening it in a new tab instead of a popup.

Comment: Thanks, Coleman for getting back to me. I did try the fix you posted but it didn't seem to help. I also checked the demo site and it still gives the loading failed dialog. I debugged as you suggested and get a red error message that says 403 Forbidden 812 ms and the following response underneath: 

Ticket #11289, IE bug fix: always pad the error page with enough characters such that it is greater than 512 bytes, even after gzip compression abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkk........ 
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.