# 4.6.6 Wordpress still does not allow me to credit to a PCP

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, pcp, personal-campaign-pages

I posted about this earlier here: ["Loading Failed" when soft crediting to a Personal Campaign Page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/loading-failed-when-soft-crediting-to-a-personal-campaign-page)

And Coleman kindly submitted a fix for it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6156

Trouble is, I was never able to get the fix to work on my end and when I check the Demo site, which is now 4.6.6, it also still fails when you try to add a PCP page.

If I edit an existing donation from either a contact's card or by searching for a contribution and use the PCP drop down and try to search for a PCP -the screen below appears. I also tried opening the contribution in a new tab (rather than the overlay edit) and got the same error. I get the same error if I try to enter a check donation from scratch and add a PCP credit.

[image]

Did I miss something in the fix or is it not really working!?

Comment: Could you edit your question with *exact* steps to reproduce this bug? I haven't been able to get the "Loading failed" message.

Comment: Hmm, I edited the question, hope I was specific enough! I also tried multiple browsers with the same result.

Comment: I did some further testing on the demo sites (as I just discovered the development sandboxes.) WordPress Civi 4.5.9 PCP crediting works. Drupal 4.5.9 PCP crediting works. But WordPress 4.6.6 PCP crediting results in 'loading failed'.  Drupal 4.6.6 PCP crediting works. (The only Joomla demo I saw was 4.6.0 but didn't have PCP as a credit option at all.)

Comment: the 4.5 series is no longer supported so that's not an issue. Sounds like in 4.6 it is working in Drupal but not WP... I hadn't tested there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out: when you checked it on the WP demo site vs Drupal it turns out there was a conflict between a wp url param and one used by the widget.

This fixes it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6351